# converting sting to char pointer

Tags: c++, qt

I want to convert `QString` in to `char*`.

How would I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: have a look a the QByteArray since that can be used for most of the stuff you use a char * for. But the QByteArray handles unicode and char * don't.

Comment: @Johan: How does QByteArray handle unicode? It handles plain character data. I would prefer QByteArray because it's safer, does memory management, and has a nice API.

Comment: @Frank: sloppy formulation on my side, a QByteArray does not know what kind of data is in it, But since it is tightly coupled with QString you can jump back and fourth and don't have to think much about it.

Answer (score 10):

Use the toAscii/toLatin1/toUtf8 QString methods to get a plain character array (QByteArray). Which method you need depends on the encoding you want the character data to be in. For other encodings see QTextCodec. From a QByteArray, you can get a const char* using QByteArray::constData() or a char* using QByteArray::data(). Use constData() wherever you can, as data() often will create a copy that is unnecessary unless you need to modify the data via the char*.

Also note that const char* data = str.toUtf8().constData() *might* work, but is dangerous as the temporary QByteArray created in toUtf8() is destroyed right after the end of statement. As the char* returned from constData() becomes invalid when the byte array is destroyed, you should keep the byte array in a temporary variable, like this:

```
const QByteArray ba = str.toUtf8(); // or toAscii, toLatin1, depending on the encoding you  want
const char* data = ba.constData();
```

Comment: Your suggestion is important, but you should rephrase this to answer his question first, then make it clear that you need to be careful not to use temporaries past their scope.

Comment: Merlyn Morgan-Graham: True, I completed it.

Comment: if you do `qDebug("string=%s",qstring.toAscii().constData())` --> the temporary QByteArray gets destroyed after qDebug() returns?

Answer (score 5):

```
char * s = qtString.toStdString().c_str();
```

Comment: That will become invalid right after the end of the statement. (as the std::string is destroyed).

Comment: in common case - no. pointer to data std::string inherit from QString, than pointer is correct before destroing QString object.

Comment: @Mark: I don't think that can be right. QString contains a unicode string, and std::string contains a char string.

Comment: That'd be only true if the std::string would be cached somehow. I tested it, the code above happens to work here, but gives Invalid Read warnings in valgrind. Keeping the std::string silences them.

Comment: Will work on some compilers some times, but can fail somewhere. Don't use this.